# How to disable a bash builtin inside a docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to disable the builtin `kill` in the bash running inside the container, and I would like to know if it is possible to run a command after the container start running, or if it is possible to run `/bash/bash` with some specific parameter to disable a builtin function.

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

in the `entrypoint.sh`, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec "$@"
```

What I know is possible to do to disable `kill` is run the command `enable -n kill` and the builtin will be disabled. But this only works if I run the command inside the container (after `exec` when I docker run).

Is there some way to disable the kill bultin in the entrypoint or in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? If someone has access to running `docker exec` then they probably also have access to `docker run`. And if they have that, it's trivial to gain root on the host. So trying to prevent them from running `kill` inside the container doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I think the only way to do this effectively would be to build a custom version of `bash` without the builtin `kill` command...but there are so many other ways of sending signals to processes (use a different shell, use `top`, write a Python/Ruby/Perl/PHP/etc script, compile some C/Go/Rust/etc code, ...) that it seems like it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @HansKilian Kill is just an example. The goal is to disable a builtin function from the bash that is provided when the container is running.

Comment: @larsks I know that there are other ways to send a signal. What I'm trying to do is exactly force the user to use different ways to do that as an exercise (in C, python, ASM, etc).

Comment: Well, then building a custom bash (or finding a shell without a `kill` builtin) may be your best choice.

Comment: In the most common case the container only runs a single process.  If you can `docker exec your-container kill 1`, then you can also `docker stop your-container`.  Also note that the `docker exec` path doesn't run a shell or the image's entrypoint script, so shell-specific setup won't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments on your question, I think the only way to do this effectively (that is, in a way that isn't easy for someone to re-enable the `kill` command) is to build a custom `bash` binary with the `kill` command disabled.

Here's one option for that; we replace the `kill` builtin with a modified command that reports `The kill command is not available in this shell.` when someone runs `kill`. This is a multi-stage Dockerfile -- we perform the custom build in the first stage, and then copy just the `bash` binary into the final image.

```
FROM docker.io/debian:bookworm AS builder

RUN apt update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  && apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf automake libtool git 

WORKDIR /src/bash
RUN git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git .
COPY <<'EOF' ./builtins/kill.def
$PRODUCES kill.c

$BUILTIN kill
$FUNCTION kill_builtin
$SHORT_DOC kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
The kill command is not available in this shell.
$END

#include <config.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "../shell.h"

int
kill_builtin (list)
     WORD_LIST *list;
{
  fprintf(stderr, "The kill command is not available in this shell.\n");
  return (EXECUTION_FAILURE);
}
EOF
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr
RUN make
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/bash && make install DESTDIR=/tmp/bash

FROM docker.io/debian:bookworm

COPY --from=builder /tmp/bash/usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash

CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
```

Using this looks like:

```
$ podman run -it --rm bash-nokill
bash-5.2# kill
The kill command is not available in this shell.
bash-5.2# help kill
kill: kill (disabled)
    The kill command is not available in this shell.
bash-5.2#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `bash --restricted` which after processing any startup file (where you can disable builtins) these restrictions are applied (among others):

- Adding or deleting builtin commands with the `-f` and `-d` options to the `enable` builtin.
- Using the `enable` builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.

see the full list at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html